# scrollIndicatorInsets out of UITableView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Can I make visible scrollIndicator ouf or frame tableview by 
`self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -5);`

tableview add on main View, and View have backgroundColor with image, I have next situation

[image]

So can I make it without enlarge width of tableView. If not I think i can easy make with method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

But I want know, maybe it is very simple, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: You could disable clipping for the tableView, but that may lead to no clipping on top and bottom of the view as well ;-)